# How to align (rotation) a face to XY plane?

Tags: rotate, sketchup

First of all i am not sure the title correctly describe what i want to do with sketchup.

A picture is worth 1000 words

### [image: strange object]

I designed this object somewhere else in my project and it was not aligned to any axe.
Now i try to get it flat on the "ground" so i can cut it properly.

I have 2 problems here that i can't figure how to fix:

1. as you can see the blue "component" box around the object has a strange alignment. If i do "explode" and then recreate the component it is better but this is not a good solution.
2. the bottom of the object may look like it is flat on the ground but it is not. If you pay attention you can see it going through the plane.

I am struggling for a long time now with the rotate tool and i can't get it to have the proper alignement of one face to the XY plane.

Comment: I think still on-topic, but it would be more suitable to ask at [Graphic Design site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketchup)

Comment: i posted this question there as you suggested and effectively got better results :)
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77722/flatten-object-in-sketchup